# "ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json" when using group by on a json sql value

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to run the following query:
`

```
SELECT e.date as date, e.headers::json->'url' as url, e.time_spent as time_spent 
FROM some_table e 
  JOIN some_table a ON e.key= a.key 
WHERE a.name='firefox' 
AND e.date BETWEEN '2022-11-15' AND '2022-11-21' 
GROUP BY url 
ORDER BY time_spent 
DESC LIMIT 30;
```

The problem is with using `GROUP BY url`. With that in place the query
returns the error:

> ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json

[Error Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyhXt.png)

Comment: Why is `headers` not defined as `jsonb` or at least as `json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) the `->` operator returns a JSON value which has no equality operator defined (so you can't compare `json` values using `=` which is needed for the GROUP BY.

You need to extract it as `text` using `->>`

```
e.headers::json->>'url'
```